# VBA Run-time error '424': Object Required

Tags: html, vba

I'm trying to parse two sets of data and I'm wondering where I'm going wrong with this code.

The portion of code in question looks like this:

```
Cells(2 + n, Target.Column) = ie.document.getElementById("yfs_l84_" & Cells(2 + n, 1)).innerText
Cells(2 + n, Target.Column + 1) = ie.document.getElementById("yfs_v53_" & Cells(2 + n, 1)).innerText
```

While the first line works fine, the second one gives an error. This is the HTML code block that I used for both lines:

```
<span class="time_rtq_ticker" >< span id="yfs_l84_mgn" >0.94 </span></span>
```

&

```
<td class="yfnc_tabledata1" ><span id="yfs_v53_mgn" >681,187</span></td>
```

Replacing mgn in the tag with whatever I have in my cell, shouldn't the data provided not error out because I used the same method? I'm confused.

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe your first value is parsed as an integer `0.94` and your second value is parsed as a string `681,187`. And a string assignment need a `Set` statement at the beginning. So for the second one, your might need : `Set Cells(2 + n, Target.Column + 1) = ie.document.getElementById("yfs_v53_" & Cells(2 + n, 1)).innerText`

Comment: The problem may not be HTML-related; it could be the lack of a parent worksheet for the [Range.Cells](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx) object. Declare a string var and assign `str = "yfs_l84_" & Cells(2 + n, 1)` then put a Watch on the *str* var to see what it is becoming.

Comment: I tried another example that contained a comma and it worked perfectly for the first one. The case is rater strange.

Comment: Is it not Target.Column + 1 is what is wrong here?

Comment: No, the + 1 sets the cell beside the other one, and works when using the same tag.